# mongoDB unique indexes not working

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, unique-index

I have a lot of documents which i indexed by the url. I created an index on url from pymongo like this

```
coll.create_index('url',unique=True,background=True)      //coll is the name of the collection
```

but still i am able to insert documents with duplicate urls.

i checked from the mongo shell whether the index actually exists and it shows 
this

```
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "url" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "dbname.coll",
        "name" : "url_1",
        "background" : true
},
```

Does setting `background=True` also mean that the uniqueness of `url` wont be checked at the instant when the document is inserted? I am totally confused why the uniqueness is not working?

Comment: The index is still in the process of building, I guess.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So when there is no `"background" : true` in the output of `getIndexes` would that mean that index creation is complete?

Comment: I'd say so, yes. To be extra sure, look in `db.currentOp()`. If the index is still building, it should be reflected there.

Comment: `db.currentOp()` shows an empty list for key `inprog`

Comment: So, does index definition still have `background` flag?

Comment: yes it has a `background` flag

Comment: But it doesn't say unique. I guess, something went wrong. Did you try to create the index in the mongo shell?

Comment: no i haven't. I think i should drop the index and then recreate an index from the shell

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I dropped the index and created it again from shell like this `db.coll.ensureIndex({url:1},{unique : true, dropDups : true})` but it took a long time(1 hour i guess) and then it gave the following message `too may dups on index build with dropDups=true` .i have about 7.5 million documents in my collection sizing about 6.6 GB

Comment: So, that must be a problem. Could you create an empty collection with this index and then reinsert all documents to it. It will take some time, but should take care of this problem.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is 7.5 million or 6.6 gb too much for a collection. I am on a 64-bit machine and using mongoDB 2.06 stable release

Comment: It depends. For AWS micro instance, for example, it's definitely too much. I'm not sure what caused the problem. How much free RAM have you got?

Comment: i am on a dedicated server(from `singlehop`) with 8 GB RAM

Comment: @SergioTulentsev A lot of people run mongoDB on cloud mostly Amazon. Are dedicated servers not a good solution?

Comment: Yes, I run dedicated servers too. Sorry, I'm out of clues on this one :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you invite some more eyes on this question? Because right now i am in development stage of my project but once its in production, moving data from one collection to others wont be good

Comment: Hmm this looks weird can you post this on mongodb-user google group?

Comment: background=True just means it was specified when the index was created, it doesn't mean the index is still being created.  Are you sure the index didn't already exist?  Did you check for errors when this create_index command was run?

Comment: note that if you have a non-unique index on this collection/field and then try to ensureIndex the same index with unique=true you won't get an error and it'll be a no-op.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky No i did not check for errors when i created the index.

Answer (score 3):

First off, `db.collection.getIndexSpecs()` should report `"unique" : true`.

In terms of inserting, my guess is, that you are doing unsafe writes. Unsafe `save` that is violating a unique index constraint actually returns a new `ObjectId` but the document in database is not changed nor a new document is saved.

You'll get a `pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError` if you try the operation with `safe=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Building a unique index with dropDups=True will fail if it encounters more than 1 million documents that need to be dropped due to having duplicate keys for the index.  If you can manually delete some duplicates to make the total duplicate count be below 1 million, then you should be able to build the index successfully.

Another option if you can't get the number of duplicates below 1 million is to take a secondary offline and bring it up as a stand-alone node, not part of the replica set.  Then you can dump the collection that needs the new index using mongodump -d  -c , then drop the collection, create the index, then restore the data using mongorestore.  Then that secondary will have the same documents, but with duplicates removed and the index built.  Then you can put that secondary back into the replica set and repeat the process on another secondary.  Finally you can step down you primary and do the same on that node one a new primary has been elected.

Comment: i did follow the second option. But pymongo should have thrown some exception when i created the unique index. It didnt and i thought index was created and documents were unique until i manually discovered that some documents were not unique